# Android Custom Listview, Cannot change element in a single row

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm creating a facebook like custom listview feed using volley.

The listview is on a Fragment and I'm using customListAdapter.java and SearchItem.java classes to load the content to the listview.

The Problem is when I click the like button or save button in a row, it changes to Liked and Saved not only in that row but also in some other rows.

In my Fragment

```
final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_popular_frag, container, false);            

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.popular_list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), PopularList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

In onItemClick of Fragment

```
holder.likes_layout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.likes_layout);
holder.saves_layout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.saves_layout);

holder.likes_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    put_like();     
                }                           
            });
```

In customListAdapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //post_id,name,user_prof_pic,post_description,post_datetime
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();



        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed_list_row, null);

    holder = new ViewHolder();

    holder.comment_layout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.comment_layout);
    holder.likes_layout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.likes_layout);
    holder.saves_layout = (LinearLayout) parent.findViewById(R.id.saves_layout);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please provide more detail of your code for proper answer.
 but as i can see here ..

holder.likes_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {

```
   put_like();     
            }                           
        });
```

you are not storing the user state in your code.So I can suggest to use a bean class for this

Comment: What do you meant by a bean class?

Comment: I already have that class, It's used to create an object and set values, but How can I store user state?


public class SearchItem {
 public String txt_title, txt_username, post_type_img, user_photo, txt_days, post_type;

 public SearchItem() {
 }

 public SearchItem(String txt_username, String txt_title, String post_type_img) {
  this.txt_username = txt_username;
  this.txt_title = txt_title;
  this.post_type_img = post_type_img;
 }

 public int getpostid() {
  return postid;
 }

 public void setpostid(int postid) {
  this.postid = postid;
 }
}